# Mysql full text search particular word

Tags: php, mysql

```
tag1 - Novel, My pession, Holi, Book, My book, Having book
tag2 - Holi Novel, My pession, Book, My book, Having book
tag3 - Romantic Novel, My Novel, Book, My book, Having book
tag4 - Novel based, My Novel, Book, My book, Having book
tag5 - Ovel based, My Novel, Book, My book, Having book, Novel
tag6 - Based, My Novel, Book, Novel, Having book, Presume
```

I want to search only those tags having `Novel`. It should be search `tag1` and `tag5`
in full text search

Comment: read this: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: You should really consider [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if you want performance and maintainability.

Comment: Yes, so you should have three tables here: `book`, `tag` and `book_tag`, with the last one having foreign keys to the other two. Then use `JOIN`s for a much faster way of doing this.

Comment: (This was downvoted as there was no detail, and no demonstration of prior effort. Please spend some time formulating good questions - the practice of doing so often will reveal the solution to you anyway!).

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE
    tag1 REGEXP '(^|, )[[:<:]]Novel[[:>:]](,|$)' AND
    tag5 REGEXP '(^|, )[[:<:]]Novel[[:>:]](,|$)'
```

Comment: Rid thanks but it is searching all tags rather than tag1 and tag5

Comment: @bhupendra, updated example, guessing that `tag1` and `tag5` are columns.

Comment: @bhupendra the you need `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( tags LIKE '%NOVEL,%' OR tags LIKE '% NOVEL%' OR tags LIKE '%,NOVEL %')`

Comment: Thanks rid but it is also sarching whole tags.

Comment: @bhupendra, updated. Still guessing what's going on in your database.

Comment: @bhupendra: if this solved your problem, please tick it - it's how we express gratitude on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I usually store each keyword in following manner

```
,Novel,My Passion,Holi,
```

i.e. comma at start and at end of string, so now instead of Novel you can search for `'%,Novel,%'` in `LIKE` command and it works like a charm.

Comment: We cant do this because we can not update 20 lacs records

Comment: From your sample, it is simple update query update table set column = "," + column + "," and record are in good format. or as other commentor, you should really normalize it for faster result. Remember TEXT search is slowest of all.

Comment: I just read other answer and you really have no option but to follow my advice from my experience :). or go normalize way.

Comment: @bhupendra, you can do this. It will take a long time to update all records, so you'll likely have a downtime period, but it's the next best thing to normalization. `LIKE` should be a lot faster than `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE subject LIKE 'Novel'

UNION

SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE subject LIKE 'Novel,%'

UNION

SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE subject LIKE '%,Novel,%'

UNION

SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE subject LIKE '%,Novel'

Comment: Thanks but It is too heavy for our database because we have more than 20 Lacs. and this query Kills our query and taking more than 40 sec.